# mongoose.agregatte no me trae el objeto con su relación

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Estoy queriendo traerme la relación mediante el metodo $lookup con mongoose y me esta trayendo un array vacio. No puedo encontrar donde se encuentra el error, si en el modelo o en la forma de que invocación de la función

Este es mi modelo de Patient donde utilizo el campo workSocialId para hacer la relación con un ObjeteId del modelo workSocial

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const patientSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
        lastname: { type: String },
        dni: {
            type: Number,
            unique: true
        },
        phone: { type: String },
        email: { type: String },
        number_affiliate: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        date_birth: { type: Date },
        workSocialId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'workSocial'
        },
        health_question: [
            {
                question: { type: String },
                status: { type: Boolean },
                description: { type: String }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('patients', patientSchema);
```

Esta es mi funcion de consulta de paciente

```
const getPatients = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await patientModel.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:{
                from: "workSocial",
                localField: "workSocialId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "obra"
            }
        }
    ]);

    res.send({ data });
}
```

Pero cuando consulto por Postman me devuelve lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me trae el objeto pero no me trae dentro del campo "obra" la relación con todos sus datos.

Comment: Si usas `ref` de Mongoose ¿Porqué usar agregación en vez de [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de un documento de patient y uno de workSocial?